# Undefined variable while accessing Associative arrays in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have two arrays, one is "OperID" the other is "OperSums". The OperID array contains ID numbers, and the OperSums array contains IDs attached to a total which looks like this:

Array 1

```
{[0] => oper1 [1] => oper2 [2] => 3 [3] => oper4 [4] => oper5 [5] => oper6 [6] => oper7 [7]       => oper8 [8] => oper9}
```

Array 2

```
{["oper3"]=> float(17498.5) ["oper1"]=> float(10383.5) ["oper2"]=> float(6277) ["oper4"]=> float(10224.67) ["oper6"]=> float(3955.65) ["oper5"]=> float(4997.78) ["oper8"]=> float(11382) ["oper9"]=> float(5072.1) ["oper7"]=> float(14759) ["oper-nb3n0hah-1tueubqo"]=> float(1033.45) ["oper-50f6e4ad-9effbec7"]=> float(3058) ["oper-4f05a90b-03b379f9"]=> float(12112.5) ["oper-4db82d0b-796a3081"]=> float(621) ["oper-qxr9ryex-bsmm0g6f"]=> string(4) "0.00" ["oper-qtgjvw8y-1uqtw058"]=> float(10023) ["oper-487b885e-dbbae536"]=> string(6) "340.00" ["oper-shcuaee2-yldfdxsd"]=> float(467) ["oper-416fd551-da6937eb"]=> float(6563) ["oper-50564d75-f1da98ec"]=> string(4) "0.00" ["oper-l65tf5ex-w5qfinca"]=> float(1746) ["oper-52657816-3d6516e2"]=> float(3495) ["oper-4a82c3be-bccc185d"]=> float(0) ["oper-1f2mnwry-nfywuasi"]=> string(6) "255.95"}
```

I'm wanting to gather only the operator values that are in both arrays and display the totals for each operator which are within each float in Array 2, and truncate all extra data. The reason I want to truncate all extra data is because I will be displaying the information in a graph. I'm really not that great with associative arrays, so any pointers or tips in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. This is in PHP by the way.

Here is the code I'm working with so far:

```
$operSums = array();

$operearnedArray[] = array(
  'amount' => $row['ChargeAmount'], 
  'id' => $row['OperatorID']);


foreach ($operearnedArray as $value) {
  if($value['id'] == '' || $value['id'] == null) {
  continue;
  }
  if(array_key_exists($value['id'], $operSums)) {
    $operSums[$value['id']] += $value['amount'];
  } else {
    $operSums[$value['id']] = $value['amount'];
  }
}

foreach ($OperSums as $id => $value) {
    if (in_array($id,$OperID)) {
        echo $id.' => '.$value;
    }
}
```

But it throws these error messages:

Notice: Undefined variable: OperSums
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

These error messages happen with the second foreach loop only

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display values from one associative array whose key exists as the value in another array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26664907/display-values-from-one-associative-array-whose-key-exists-as-the-value-in-anoth)

Answer (score 1):

It's `$operSums`, but you're passing `$OperSums` (note case)

Comment: Wow...I cannot believe I overlooked this...Thanks!!!

Comment: No probs. Please accept the answer if you deem it to be the correct answer to your question.