# Display values from one associative array whose key exists as the value in another array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have two arrays, one is "OperID" the other is "OperSums". The OperID array contains ID numbers, and the OperSums array contains IDs attached to a total which looks like this:

Array 1 (OperID)

```
{[0] => oper1 [1] => oper2 [2] => 3 [3] => oper4 [4] => oper5 [5] => oper6 [6] => oper7 [7] => oper8 [8] => oper9}
```

Array 2 (OperSums)

```
{["oper3"]=> float(17498.5) ["oper1"]=> float(10383.5) ["oper2"]=> float(6277) ["oper4"]=> float(10224.67) ["oper6"]=> float(3955.65) ["oper5"]=> float(4997.78) ["oper8"]=> float(11382) ["oper9"]=> float(5072.1) ["oper7"]=> float(14759) ["oper-nb3n0hah-1tueubqo"]=> float(1033.45) ["oper-50f6e4ad-9effbec7"]=> float(3058) ["oper-4f05a90b-03b379f9"]=> float(12112.5) ["oper-4db82d0b-796a3081"]=> float(621) ["oper-qxr9ryex-bsmm0g6f"]=> string(4) "0.00" ["oper-qtgjvw8y-1uqtw058"]=> float(10023) ["oper-487b885e-dbbae536"]=> string(6) "340.00" ["oper-shcuaee2-yldfdxsd"]=> float(467) ["oper-416fd551-da6937eb"]=> float(6563) ["oper-50564d75-f1da98ec"]=> string(4) "0.00" ["oper-l65tf5ex-w5qfinca"]=> float(1746) ["oper-52657816-3d6516e2"]=> float(3495) ["oper-4a82c3be-bccc185d"]=> float(0) ["oper-1f2mnwry-nfywuasi"]=> string(6) "255.95"}
```

I'm wanting to gather only the operator values that are in both arrays and display the totals for each operator which are within each float in Array 2, and truncate all extra data. I'm really not that great with associative arrays, so any pointers or tips in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. This is in PHP by the way.

Here is the code I'm working with so far:

```
$operSums = array();

$operearnedArray[] = array(
      'amount' => $row['ChargeAmount'], 
      'id' => $row['OperatorID']);


foreach ($operearnedArray as $value) {
      if($value['id'] == '' || $value['id'] == null) {
      continue;
      }
      if(array_key_exists($value['id'], $operSums)) {
        $operSums[$value['id']] += $value['amount'];
      } else {
        $operSums[$value['id']] = $value['amount'];
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you just need to step through $OperSums (Array 2) and display the value if the key exists in $OperID (Array 1)?

```
foreach ($OperSums as $id => $value) {
    if (in_array($id,$OperID)) {
        echo $id.' => '.$value;
    }
}
```

If you actually need to "truncate all extra data" then unset the arrays as you go (or create a new array), although that does not seem necessary if you are just displaying the results?

Comment: I'm needing to truncate all the extra data because I have a graph that is displaying the results. I'm trying to see if I can use your code to help, but it throws the following errors: Notice: Undefined variable: OperSums && Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: You obviously need to change the variable names to match the ones used in your code. You initially referred to the arrays as "OperID" and "OperSums", however, your code example appears to differ?